# jQuery selector issue?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables.

```
 <table border="1" class="a">
            <tr>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Value 2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>




        <table border="1"  class="b">
            <tr>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Value 2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

On table #1 I write :

```
  $(".a td:parent").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

and the result is :

[image]

Notice the green one which *wasn't* faded out .

But it doesn't make sence. I wrote "go to *parent* - which is the **TR** and fade it all"

Ok maybe the answer is that because it doesn't have a value inside while the other 3 `td's` has.

So I tested (on the *second* table):

```
$(".b tr").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

and it did faded the *All* TR's  (although the last cell is empty)....

[image]

What is going on here?

jsbin : http://jsbin.com/ehacen/1/edit

Comment: `:parent` does something else: http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/ "Select all elements that are the parent of another element, including text nodes." "This is the inverse of :empty."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the first example. According to the API ( http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/), `:parent` selects that have content inside them. So the first selector is saying "get all `<td>`s that have content in them", so it only selects the first three `<td>`s. To select all the parents of the `<td>`s, use this:

```
$('.a td').parent()
```

Hope this clears it up for you!

Comment: I think you should use `parent()`, because you only want to select  the direct parent `<tr>`s.

Answer (score 2):

the selector [:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) will look into the td with a child (in this example all of your three td has a textNode as a child and not the last one. [:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) isnt going up the dom tree that you will need to use:

```
$(".a td").parent().fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

or if you want to use :parent:

```
$(".a tr:parent").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

I think you need to wait until CSS4 comes with their parent selector http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/

Answer (score 0):

If you are building some more complex selector then you can use the `:has()` selector:

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```
$(".a tr:has(td)").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```